# Why use sorting algorithm versus database doing it?

Tags: database, arrays, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I'm curious if there are any advantages to writing your own sorting algorithm when programming something that needs sorting versus simply using a database to sort the data? The only thing i can think of would be if the data set is small enough where it wouldn't be worth it to set up a database with some queries + the extra time that it would take to feed the data back and forth to the program. Databases do a pretty good job at sorting efficiently so besides what i mentioned above, i have no clue.

Comment: Well, if your data is in a database, then you may well choose to let it sort. But your data may not be in a database.

Comment: And if your dataset is *not* in a database, then it is virtually *never* worth it to feed the data back and forth just to sort it, regardless of the size of the dataset. In such cases, you should sort it in-program.

Comment: Yes, you can avoid database sorting if dataset is small or provided by end user and not present in db. Another use case I can think of is that parameter on which you are sorting is not part of db column, a and you are using this custom parameter for sorting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One common reason to employ a sorting algorithm outside of the database is to provide sorting facilities controlled by end-users of your system in the presentation layer. In situations like that it would be too costly to go back to the database and fetch the information that you already have simply for the sake of having it sorted differently.

However, it is highly unusual to implement sorting yourself: all popular and most not-so-popular programming environments supply built-in sorting facilities, recognizing their widespread use.

Answer (score 0):

you should implement sorting outside the database when your key field is complex and you need complex comparators to sort them.